# Cannot unlock Motorola C following the instructions from Motorola

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, motorola

I have:

- Created an account with Motorola
- Enabled developer mode
- Enabled "OEM unlocking"
- Enabled USB debugging
- Disabled the lock-screen PIN

I then connected the device to my PC with a USB cable and booted the device while holding volume down.

The device is visible to `fastboot`:

```
$ fastboot devices               
ZY322V73DQ  fastboot
```

However, I cannot run any "oem" commands:

```
$ fastboot oem get_unlock_data 
...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.002s
```

How can I unlock my Motorola C?

---

Here is everything else:

```
$ fastboot getvar all          
(bootloader)    max-download-size: 0x8000000
(bootloader)    partition-size:flashinfo: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:flashinfo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:userdata: 32000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:userdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:cache: 19000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:cache: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:system: c0000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:system: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:metadata: 2480000
(bootloader)    partition-type:metadata: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvdata: 2000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:frp: 100000
(bootloader)    partition-type:frp: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:efuse: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:efuse: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee2: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee2: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee1: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee1: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:keystore: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:keystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:secro: 600000
(bootloader)    partition-type:secro: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:oemkeystore: 200000
(bootloader)    partition-type:oemkeystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:seccfg: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:seccfg: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:expdb: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:expdb: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:logo: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:logo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:recovery: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:recovery: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:boot: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:boot: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:para: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:para: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lk: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lk: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect2: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect2: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect1: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect1: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvram: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvram: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:proinfo: 300000
(bootloader)    partition-type:proinfo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:preloader: 40000
(bootloader)    partition-type:preloader: raw data
(bootloader)    ro.carrier: 3gb
(bootloader)    radio: 5
(bootloader)    kernel.version[0]: Linux version 3.18.35+
(bootloader)    kernel.version[1]: (zhaopan@dell-PowerEdge-R730)
(bootloader)    kernel.version[2]: gcc version 4.8 (GCC)
(bootloader)    kernel.version[3]: 1 SMP PREEMPT
(bootloader)    kernel.version[4]: 2019-03-26:11:19:45
(bootloader)    ro.build.fingerprint[1]: motorola/namath_54/namath:7.0/NRD
(bootloader)    ro.build.fingerprint[2]: D90M.009/1553569854:user/release-
(bootloader)    ro.build.fingerprint[3]: -keys
(bootloader)    ro.build.version.mtk[1]: alps-mp-n0.mp1-V1.0.2_wt6737m.65.
(bootloader)    ro.build.version.mtk[2]: .n_P109
(bootloader)    ro.build.version.full[1]: Blur_Version.25.41.09.namath_54.
(bootloader)    ro.build.version.full[2]: 3gb.en.US
(bootloader)    imei1: 000000000000000
(bootloader)    boot reason: wdt_by_pass_pwk
(bootloader)    hwrev: M11
(bootloader)    CID: 0x0032
(bootloader)    SKU: XT1754
(bootloader)    CPU: "MT6735"
(bootloader)    serialno: ZY322V73DQ
(bootloader)    off-mode-charge: 1
(bootloader)    warranty: yes
(bootloader)    securestate: no
(bootloader)    hwsecure: yes
(bootloader)    kernel: lk
(bootloader)    board: WT98736B32_BB8
(bootloader)    product: WT98736B32_BB8
(bootloader)    Ram size: 1GB
(bootloader)    emmc: KMFE60012M_B214
(bootloader)    storage-type: emmc
(bootloader)    version-preloader: 0.1.00
(bootloader)    version: 0.5
all: Done!!
finished. total time: 0.006s
```

Comment: might not be unlockable. i have seen some tuts recommending mfastboot instead of fastboot, give it a shot. rooting with locked bootloader might possible if you set keep force encryption and keep avb verity in Magisk Manager advanced settings, find the right MTK_AllInOne_DA.bin and auth_sv5.auth and flash patched boot-verified.img

Comment: https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files

Comment: only if SP Flash Tool fails as descriped above: suboot script (not for noobs)
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79626434&postcount=135
or as app (untested)
https://github.com/JunioJsv/mtk-easy-su